# How to access the adapter controls from activity?

Tags: android

[image]

In Base adapter, I have used some imageview, can I change the image src in activity?

Comment: please read these: [page1](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [page2](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) [page3](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not access the adapter views directly in activity. Write a method in adapter instead. Call adapter.change image from your activity.

```
public void changeImage(int imgResId) {
   likeButton.setImageResource(imgResId);
}
```

Comment: thnks bro, i was create one method in adapter, if success in activity i had called that method ........

Answer (score 1):

If Image src is provided from activity then you can call **`notifyDataSetChanged()`** after changing data.

Eg.

```
adapter = new MYAdapter(data);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
//change data here
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: imageview is in adapter, but i want to change the src from activity ?

Comment: Can you show me how you are sending data to adapter at first ??

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the model data which is associated with ViewHolder after that just notify the adapter and adapter will update your item with new model data.

Take example if you have Array of 10 objects and you want to update ImageView on 5th position then update your 5th model in ArrayList and call **adapter.notifyDataSetChange()** it will update desired image view.